# How to display indoor floors with Google Maps API (web)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-indoor-maps

I need to display the indoor floors of a shopping center (already mapped and visible on maps.google.com) but after implementing a basic Google Maps JavaScript API those indoor floors do not show up in the map (just the first one).
Can the Javascript API show the different floors? and if yes, how can I implement it?

I implemented a "Base Map" from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=vi

Comment: Do you have the tiles/images for those floors?

Comment: well, the mall is already mapped on Google Maps, lets take this as an example :  https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/40+Boulevard+Haussmann,+75009+Paris,+France/@48.8736601,2.3320272,20.38z/data=!3m1!5s0x47e66e3704579fb5:0xb825fcec116a04ac!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x47e66e34301e2a45:0x608e0f8b09755e6e!2sPrintemps+de+l'Homme!3m1!1s0x47e66e3703e3bbb7:0x761a43269d50e900. How would I have the tiles/images from those floors?

Comment: Did you manage to work this out?

Comment: @eddyoc I answered the post. It's still not supported according to the bugtracker

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question in case someone comes by this post.
According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35819848 it does not seem to be supported.